# Proove verification: $\int_{0}^{1}I_{\omega \notin \mathbb{Q}}(w) d\mathbb{P(\omega )}=1$ using Borel Cantelli lemma

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am just a student in probability theory and I am trying to understand by myself why: $\int_{0}^{1}I_{\omega \notin \mathbb{Q}}(w) d\mu(\omega )=1$  with $\mu (\omega )$ the Lebesgues measure.

1-To show it i thought first:
$\int_{0}^{1}I_{\omega  \notin \mathbb{Q}}(\omega) d \mu (\omega)=\mu(\omega  \notin \mathbb{Q})=1-\mu(\omega  \in \mathbb{Q})$

2-So now i will focus on trying to proove that $\mu(\omega  \in \mathbb{Q})=0$
To do it I ll proceed as follow.
First let pick an arbitrary rationnal number $x_1$ on $]0;1[$ that means $x_1 \in \mathbb{Q} \cap ]0;1[$
We know that it exists $(\alpha _1;\beta _1) \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0;1]$ s.t. $\alpha _1< x_1<\beta _1$ So of course: $0 \leq \mathbb{P} (X=x_1) < \mathbb{P} (\alpha _1 \leq X \leq \beta _1)\leq \frac{1}{1}$ because $x_1 \in ]\alpha _1;\beta _1[$
Now we choose an other rationnal number $ x_1 \neq x_2 \in \mathbb{Q} \cap ]0;1[$ and we proceed exactly in the same way as for $x_1$ but now we require $(\alpha _2;\beta _2) \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0;1]$ such that: $0 \leq \mu (X=x_2) < \mu (\alpha _2 \leq X \leq \beta _2)\leq \frac{1}{2^2}$. Such $(\alpha _2;\beta _2)$ of course exist (we can even construc them from $x_2$)
...etc...
We proceed exactly the same way for each rationnal number that we writte $x_n$ (that we know are countable). We know that for each of those rationnal number $x_n, \exists (\alpha _n;\beta _n)\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0;1] \ \  s.t. \ \ \alpha _n<x_n<\beta _n$ and that verify:$0 \leq \mu (X=x_n) < \mu (\alpha _n \leq X \leq \beta _n)\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$
Rem: Such $\alpha _n,\beta _n$ always exist because for exemple we can construct them as follow: $\alpha _n=x_n-1/2n^3$ and $\beta _n=x_n+1/2n^3$

3-Now we have: $\sum_{0 \leq x_n \in \mathbb{Q} \leq 1}^{} \mu(X=x_n) \leq \sum_{0 \leq x_n \in \mathbb{Q} \leq 1}^{} \mu(\alpha_n \leq X \leq \beta_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty 
$
And by using BC lemma we cannow conclude that: $\mu(\omega  \in \mathbb{Q})=0$
Q.E.D

Is this correct? I haven't somebody to really ask him this question so i will be happy to read your comment.
Thank you

Comment: $\mu \{x\}=0$ for every $x$ and this impies $\mu (A)=0$ for any countable set $A$. You don't have to play with rational numbers at all.

Comment: @geetha290krm i understood what you said (that there is a quicker way to proove it) but does this make my proof wrong?

Comment: @geetha290krm Btw this integral in the question is not necessarly correct (i mean equal to one) for every measure $\mathbb{P}(w)$ right?

Comment: Borel-Cantelli is not appropriate here: That deals with a sequence of events that either happen infinitely often or finitely often. If your events are $\{X=x_n\}$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ then, if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ values are distinct, clearly that can happen at most once (and hence at most finitely often) for any distribution on $X$, including $X=x_1$ with prob 1.

Comment: Also your statement $(\alpha_1; \beta_1) \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0;1]$ is either unclear or incorrect.  I don't know what the semi-colon means, and I do not know if you mean $\subseteq$ instead of $\in$.  Either way, if  $(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$ is intended to be a nonempty interval, then it is impossible for a nonempty interval to be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ because the rationals contain "holes."

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your comment. 
I didn't really well understand why i can't use BC here as it seems to me that i verify all the condition for using BC

Comment: Indeed you have all the conditions required to prove that $\{X=x_n\}$ occurs finitely often (almost surely) by BC, which is a result that we knew already without BC because (surely) at most one of those events can hold if $x_n$ values are distinct.

Comment: @Michael I simply meant that it exists two rationnal number $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ in the interval $[0;1]$ that satisfy the property that came after. Here $ (\alpha_n ; \beta_n )$ is NOT an intervall. It's just a couple of two values. 
I writte an open intervall as follow: $]a;b[$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137046/discussion-between-x0-user-0x-and-michael).